# handlebars subexpressions not working for me

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

template.hbs

```
    <div>
    {{helperOne  (subExpHelper 'test string') }}
    </div>
```

helperone.js

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper('helperOne', function(input) {
  return new Handlebars.SafeString(input);
});
```

helpertwo.js

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper('subExpHelper', function(input) {
  return new Handlebars.SafeString(input);
});
```

The error I get from grunt

Running "emberTemplates:dist" (emberTemplates) task

> > Error: Parse error on line 8:
> >     ...v>    {{helperOne  (subExpHelper 'test 
> >     ----------------------^
> >     Expecting 'CLOSE', 'CLOSE_UNESCAPED', 'STRING', 'INTEGER', 'BOOLEAN', 'ID', 'DATA', 'SEP', got 'INVALID'
> >     Warning: Ember Handlebars failed to compile app/templates/portfolio.hbs. Use --force to continue.

subexpressions don't work until handlebars 1.3.0 which according to my chrome resources is the version being loaded.

Comment: This works for me. Which Grunt plugin are you using for precompiling your Ember Handlebars templates and which version?

Comment: had to do a LOT of digging (im new to everything javascript and their build tools) but I am indeed compiling with 1.0 >.< I'll figure out how to change the compiling version, thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  Feel free to answer and I'll accept

Comment: Tell me about it :) It took me a while to learn to see trees in that forest. Btw, I suggest picking Gulp over Grunt in the long run, if you want to stay sane. Good luck!

Comment: Take a look at [ember-cli](http://iamstef.net/ember-cli/) for building ember apps. It will eventually be The Ember Way™ of building ember apps once it hits 1.0. It is was started by an Ember Core team member, with tons of people contributing

Comment: @DanMcClain  How painful would it be to move a Yeoman project over to ember-cli at this point in ember-cli's development?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message indicates that subexpressions aren't supported, so you **are** using an outdated version of Handlebars. See if you can update it or find a better plugin ([grunt-ember-templates](https://github.com/dgeb/grunt-ember-templates) is a pretty popular pick).